# Custom prices IF product ID =

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I have a custom table built to override WooCommerce prices. The table is called wp_get_pricing. Currently the code below (along with multiple other attempts at this) stops at the first IF statement and makes all the products the same price even if the product ID is not in the IF statements below.

```
function return_custom_price($product, $price) {
global $savedzip;   

$products_array = wc_get_product( id );

$column_ids='';
if ($products_array = '846') {
$column_ids = 'five_resident';  }
elseif ($products_array = '1477') {
$column_ids = 'six_resident';}
elseif ($products_array = '1603') {
$column_ids = 'thirty_commercial';}
elseif ($products_array = '1602') {
$column_ids = 'twenty_commercial';}
elseif ($products_array = '1600') {
$column_ids = 'fifteen_commercial';}
elseif ($products_array = '1322') {
$column_ids = 'thirty_resident';}
elseif ($products_array = '1316') {
$column_ids = 'twenty_resident';}
elseif ($products_array = '1314') {
$column_ids = 'fifteen_resident';}
elseif ($products_array = '1313') {
$column_ids = 'ten_resident';}
else  {
    $column_ids = "residential";} 

$price = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT $column_ids FROM wp_get_pricing WHERE zip='$savedzip'");
return $price;

 }
  add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

if I change $products_array to = $product->id() the frontend of the website returns a blank page. Any help is appreciated.

*UPDATE*
I changed

```
 $products_array = wc_get_product( id )
```

to

```
 $FindID = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status='publish'", ARRAY_A);
```

which gave me the below when I did a var_dump

```
 array(20) { [0]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "81" } [1]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "577" } [2]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "846" } [3]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1306" } [4]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1311" } [5]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1313" } [6]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1314" } [7]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1316" } [8]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1322" } [9]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1324" } [10]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1477" } [11]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1592" } [12]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1593" } [13]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1598" } [14]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1600" } [15]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1602" } [16]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1603" } [17]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1605" } [18]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1665" } [19]=> array(1) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "1670" } }
```

Updating $products_array = to

```
$products_array = $findID->ID;
```

IF $products_array = returns only the first value and makes all the products the same price as the product with ID 846.

IF $products_array == returns the ELSE

Answer (score 0):

Of course this has to happen because `=` is an assignment operator. If 846 is assigned successfully to `$products_array` the conditional code is executed. You should rather use `==` to compare.

Comment: If I change if $products_array = 'ID#' to $products_array == 'ID#' it returns 0.00 for every product.

Comment: just var_dump your `$products_array` and lets see what you get

Comment: Updated my question to reflect the updates I made. Still no luck

Comment: what is the data type of your `id`

Comment: bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT